# Inheritance with ActiveRecord at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, activerecord

I have a class 'Report' that has columns 'description', 'pending', etc.

```
/app/models/report.rb
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
end


class CreateReports < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.boolean :pending, :default => true
      t.boolean :accepted, :default => false
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

But I also have two other classes: ReportPost (when a User report a Post), and ReportTopic (when a User report a Topic). I used this approach because I can user 'belongs_to :topic' for ReportTopic and 'belongs_to :post' for ReportPost. So, here comes the problem:

Since ReportPost and ReportTopic have the same columns of 'Report', I need to use the inheritance from 'Report'. But I also need to use ActiveRecord inheritance to capture new attributes from :report_topic migrates.

But, how?

Here are the other classes:

```
class ReportTopic < Report
  belongs_to :topic
end


class ReportPost < Report
  belongs_to :post
end
```

`And, the migrates:

```
class CreateReportPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :report_posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :post

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end


class CreateReportTopics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :report_topics do |t|
      t.belongs_to :topic

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Single Table Inheritance (STI) in this case. Just add a column named 'type' to your report table.

```
  def change
    create_table :reports do |t|
      t.boolean :pending, :default => true
      t.boolean :accepted, :default => false
      t.text :description
      t.string :type
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

Rails will understand this as STI. Any subclass that you may create will have its type equal to the name of the class (e.g. type = 'ReportTopic')

Comment: I already try'd this approach. The problem is: how I add the column 'post_id' directly (and only) to 'ReportPost' model, and column 'topic_id' to 'ReportTopic' model?

Comment: Hmm. What you could do is having a polymorphic association in the Report table to those two models (Post & Topic).